# Prevent Powershell from Updating Original Variable when another variable it is assigned to is changed

Tags: powershell

Here is a demo code. The `$ReferenceHash` keeps changing too when I manipulate `$tempHash` inside the function. I assume this is because it uses the same memory location. I would like to prevent this behavior so I can use `$RefenceHash` later in the code to restore the value of `$tempHash` to the original.

Maybe something simple but how would I go about that?

```
$ReferenceHash = @{PD="PROD";NP="NonProd";SB="Sandbox"}
$tempHash = $ReferenceHash
$value = "SB"

function Spit-NewHash ($tmp, $val)
{
    $tmp.remove($val)
    Return $tmp
}
$hash = Spit-NewHash -tmp $tempHash -val $value

$ReferenceHash
```

Comment: Neither `$ReferenceHash` nor `$tempHash` is changing.  The `Hashtable` to which they refer _is_.  The solution is to not have them reference the same `Hashtable` instance.

Comment: you would need to copy the 1st to the 2nd. all that _assignment_ does is create a new reference to the 1st.

Comment: `$tempHash = $ReferenceHash` --> `$tempHash = $ReferenceHash.Clone()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `Clone()`

```
$ReferenceHash = @{PD="PROD";NP="NonProd";SB="Sandbox"}
$tempHash = $ReferenceHash.Clone()
$value = "SB"

function Spit-NewHash ($tmp, $val)
{
    $tmp.Remove($val)
    return $tmp
}

$hash = Spit-NewHash -tmp $tempHash -val $value

$ReferenceHash
```

Response is

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
NP                             NonProd                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
SB                             Sandbox                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
PD                             PROD
```